# jquery - further querying "this"

Tags: jquery-selectors

i want to further use css selectors on "this" how can i do it? specifically i am trying to select this's sibiling ul > li > a's

how can i do it?

```
this + ul > li > a
```

i find that using sibling i cannot do .sibling("ul > li > a"), but i can use 3 .siblings() to do it? maybe i am using the wrong function? maybe i shld use find()? but the 1st "operator" i want is to get the sibling ul (i think i can also use next("ul")?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$('ul>li>a', this) if I understood correctly.

Or

$(this).siblings('ul').find('>li>a')